# Why aren't my .NET Core log messages showing up in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, .net-core

I've tried various attempts at getting logging to show in Azure, but nothing is working. My latest attempt was this:
https://ardalis.com/configuring-logging-in-azure-app-services/

I added this to my project:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices

In Programs.cs, I did this:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                });
            });
```

And I have this line in an API controller method that gets called:

```
_logger.LogWarning("Test warning logging.");
```

I also tried logging this way:

```
Trace.TraceWarning("Test warning logging (trace).");
```

My Azure App Service Logs settings look like this:

[image]

Yet, when I go to log stream, there are never any messages:

[image]

I'm at a lost as to what to try next.

Comment: The log stream interface is, to be excessively polite, cantankerous - but you should see at least _something_ there, if it's actually working. Maybe try refreshing the log interface in the azure portal to see if _anything_ appears, and then look for your own log messages? With a log level of `verbose` you should be seeing lots of stuff.

Comment: I see logging in "Web Server logs," but not "Application logs." But even though I see logging, I don't see *my* log messages.

Comment: @BobHorn, is it a .net core 3.1 project or other version of .net core like 2.2 etc.?

Comment: @IvanYang It's .NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Programs.cs, the `ConfigureLogging(logging=>{xxx})` should not be placed within `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`. You should use the following code in your Programs.cs:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging=> {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Then I'm using this line of code to send logs:

```
_logger.LogInformation("this is an information from index page...");
```

Then in azure portal, the message is there:

[image]